# Reading the MDG technology imported to model using C# addin

Tags: enterprise-architect

We have a model in which the MDG is imported. Now I want to read the MDG XML file to find the specific tagged value type whether it is of type combo/refguidlist. So how can we fetch the MDG technology from Addin imported to the model.

Answer (score 1):

Not that easy. The registry is a starting point. To detect whether a MDG is enabled you can inspect

```
\\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Sparx Systems\EA400\EA\OPTIONS\MDG_TECHNOLOGY_STATUS
```

where you find something like `Archimate=0;` in a semicolon separated list. In the same key location you find

```
"MDGTechnology PathList"
```

which holds a comma (!) separated list of paths where MDGs are looked after besides

```
%programfiles%\Sparx Systems\EA\MDGTechnologies
```

Now you can combine both and traverse the paths to find the appropriate MDG files and read them with the usual file operations.

Answer (score 0):

MDG's imported into the model are stored in the table `t_document`

Execute

```
select * from t_document where ElementType = 'TECHNOLOGY'
```

The actual content of the MDG technology file is stored in the column `BinContent` but I haven't figured out how to decode and read the contents of that column.

Comment: Geert, you should note that this does not work for the "standard" MDGs.

Comment: @ThomasKilian The question is specifically about MDG's imported in the model, and I do mention "imported into the model" in the answer as well.